# SSIS Package execute returns Failure, but no errors or execptions appear

Tags: c#, ssis, package

I'm having a big issue with executing SSIS package from c# code. Package is loading fine, I can see all its parameters, values etc. But when it comes to executing the package it runs fine, no errors on package, no exception on application site, but the result is Failure.

My package is really simple, as it just creates a new folder on execution. When I execute package directly from SSIS project it does its job, but when I execute it from code it returns Failure and nothing happens....

Here's my code:

```
DTSExecResult results = new DTSExecResult();

            try
            {
                results = vm.Packages[0].Execute();

                if (results.ToString() == "Failure")
                {
                    string err = "";
                    foreach (DtsError local_DtsError in vm.Packages[0].Errors)
                    {
                        string error = local_DtsError.Description.ToString();
                        err = err + error;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
            }

            ViewBag.Result = results.ToString();
```

I'm running out of ideas.... Please help!

Comment: Permissions on system where folder is to be created?

Comment: The issue also appears when package doesn't do anything... so I assume it's not an issue with permission on folders...

Comment: But you say the package works successfully when executed from BIDS/SSDT but not when executed from your C# application.

Comment: I see what you mean... Are you able to indicate how can I change those permissions? Many thanks

Comment: how about a comparison of if(results == DTSExecResult.Failure)

Comment: @marczulajtis you need to find out what windows user the C# application runs under, and give permissions to the folder to *that* user.  If you don't already know what user, from how the package is executed... there are multiple ways to find out.  For example, if this is all executing from a windows scheduler process, then the history will tell you what user it executes under.  Here's a link to getting C# to tell you which user:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260701/determine-from-within-code-which-user-my-process-is-running-as

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I checked and both app and package are running under the same user, which is also an Administrator. But I still cannot perform any file operations and no errors / exceptions appear. Every other package task that is not connected with File operations is executing properly. And I performed more tests on other pc and it gives the same results - Failure on app and no exceptions or errors, but when the package runs directly from SSDT everything's working fine.

Comment: Look in the Windows Event Viewer and check the Application, Security and System logs for any errors logged by the OS around the time you run the process. If it's permission related then it may give you more specifics.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
foreach (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsError local_DtsError in ssisPackage.Errors)
     { resultado = local_DtsError.Description; }
```